# Facebook like-box not working after new page design (Timeline) update

Tags: web, facebook-likebox

Just updated my business page to the new timeline design update... Anyone experiencing problems getting the like buttons on their websites to function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to HTTPS to fix. I figure mine was using the older code.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed the xfbml format for like boxes, and any page upgraded to timeline will get an error if using the old format.  I'm not sure if the iframe or js versions also have compatibility issues.

It used to be:

```
<fb:like-box profile_id=NUMERIC_ID . . .
```

Now it is:

```
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE_USERNAME" . . .
```

The quickest fix is to go generate a fresh snippet here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/